# ! -z "$SERVICE" -a "$SERVICE" != "" and it's function

Tags: bash

I have a bash script as follow

```
SERVICE="sssss"
if [ ! -z "$SERVICE" -a "$SERVICE" != "" ]; then
  echo "ssss"
fi
```

I am not really familiar with bash. I am using this to make sure SERVICE is not empty.

can I instead use below instead of the above?

```
if [ -n "$SERVICE" ]; then #...
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: trying to see if SERVICE is empty undefined or "" if yes I do not want to get into that if else.

Comment: `! -z "$SERVICE"` and `"$SERVICE != ""` are the same thing

Comment: how about this?  -n "$SERVICE" @thatotherguy

Comment: Also the same as the other two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the safer `[[` test in `bash` and you don't need to bother about enclosing potentially empty strings with `"`, avoiding many pitfalls.

And, yes, use `-n` for testing that the length of the expanded variable is non-zero:

```
#!/bin/bash

SERVICE="sssss"
if [[ -n $SERVICE ]]; then
  echo "ssss"
fi
```